# Call third party API server side with .NET and pass variable to use in Javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I am attempting to utilize a third party API, WebPurify, that does not allow CORS. How would I go about writing a .NET function that receives a string from client side script, call third party API server side, and then pass returned value to be used client side in javascript?

Comment: How would I go about proxying the calls to the service via a server side script on my side. Hoping to be pointed in the right direction on how to go about doing this.

Comment: Start by finding out how to make a HTTP request with .Net.  When you can do that you're almost there.  You just need to call that code from Javascript (WebApi Controller is straight-forward).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a HTTP request to your own server (via AJAX if you like). Pass the value you need in the body or querystring (as appropriate to the circumstances). The script in your own server then makes a new HTTP request to the remote API. Since it's coming from a non-AJAX environment, it will not be subject to CORS restrictions. Then you can get the response from that API and return it directly as the response to your action method.

It should be a pretty straightforward process. You tagged ASP.NET Web API, so I'll mention that in .NET libraries like System.Net.Http.HttpClient can help you make HTTP requests easily from the server-side. There are lots of general examples and documentation available online about usage, so I won't repeat that here.